# Manipulating custom variables for event tracking, Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, session-variables, event-tracking

I would like to track as a GOAL (somehow we CAN'T use segments - don't ask why, it's a mystery:)) that a user visits two kinds of subpages of my site.

I tried to make it with implementing codes to all of the subpages "A type" and other codes to subpages "B type". The code was this:

For SubPage "A":

```
_gaq.push(function() { 
     _gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "SubPage_A", "Yes", 2]); 
      var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName(); 
      if (pageTracker._getVisitorCustomVar(2) == "Yes")  {
             if (pageTracker._getVisitorCustomVar(3) != "Yes") { 
                   pageTracker._trackEvent("SubA+SubB", "Pageview"); 
                  _gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 3, "isTracked", "Yes", 2]);
            }
     }
});
```

For SubPage "B":

```
_gaq.push(function() { 
     _gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 2, "SubPage_B", "Yes", 2]); 
      var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName(); 
      if (pageTracker._getVisitorCustomVar(1) == "Yes")  {
             if (pageTracker._getVisitorCustomVar(3) != "Yes") { 
                   pageTracker._trackEvent("SubA+SubB", "Pageview"); 
                  _gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 3, "isTracked", "Yes", 2]);
            }
     }   
});
```

However, this doesn't work, since _getVisitorCustomVar can't get back the session-scoped custom variable's value, only the visitor-scoped ones'. What would you recommend for this? We really would like to track these session-based and don't want to manipulate VisitorCookieTimeout, as we would loose other informations. Is it possible to somehow get the session-based CV-s value???

I would really appreciate any answers,
Adam